# codeigniter batch_update-insert confirmation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this function that does following

```
function save($owner,$data){
///$owner='00002';$data=[['type1','value1'],['type','value2']];
///check if this $data is already in database, if +ve and != then update else insert
        $sel='';$rs=[];$ins=FALSE;$up=FALSE;$end=[];

        $this->db->select('id,type,value')->where('owner',$owner)

        //building WHERE statment
        foreach(array_keys($data)as $k)
            $sel.="type='$k' OR ";

        $this->db->where("(".trim($sel,' OR ').")");

        $r=$this->db->get('settings');

        if($r->num_rows() > 0)//building reference array
            foreach($r->result() as $r)$rs[$r->type]=$r;

        foreach($data as $t=>$v)
        {
            if(isset($rs[$t])){//case input already in db-->update
                if(!$v || $v!=$rs[$t]->value)$up[]=['id'=>$rs[$t]->id,'value'=>$v,'archived'=>0];
            }else{//case not-->insert
                if($v)$ins[]=['type'=>$t,'value'=>$v,'owner'=>$owner];
            }   
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('settings',$ins);
        $this->db->update_batch('settings',$up,'id');
    }
```

Now how can i confirm that insert_batch and update_patch both worked and how return how many fields where updated ..
i tried using db->affected_rows() but since im using 2 statements its return is not accurate.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

how about creating a variable for it?

```
private $inserted_num_rows;
private $updated_num_rows;
```

then store to the affected rows

```
$this->db->insert_batch('settings',$ins);
$this->inserted_num_rows = $this->db->affected_rows();

$this->db->update_batch('settings',$up,'id');
$this->updated_num_rows = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

then just create a `getter` to return data

```
function get_inserted_num_rows()
{
   return $this->inserted_num_rows;
}
```

AND

```
function get_updated_num_rows()
{
   return $this->updated_num_rows;
}
```